# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Error deploying adapters to server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have migrated my Worklight Server from version 5.0.6.1 to 6.0.0.1. Server is configured to work with DB2 database.

Every time I'm trying to deploy adapters, always the same error is returned both from Worklight Console and from Ant scripts:

> [adapter-deployer] Oct 17, 2013 2:28:59 PM
>   com.worklight.ant.deployers.AbstractDeployerTask logDeployResponse
>   [adapter-deployer] SEVERE: The 'adapter' version 'null' is different
>   than the version of Worklight Server '6.0.0'. [adapter-deployer] Use
>   Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.

Both versions of Worklight Studio and Worklight Server are the same: 6.0.0.20130926-1933

I rebuilt all the project several time, but the error still persists.
I didn't find a way where the adapter version should be set.

Anyone could help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you **re-build** the project's app and adapter **using Worklight Studio** (the Eclipse plug-in, not the the Ant builder scripts)?

After installing the 6.0.0.1 plug-in, did the project upgrade succeed? Do you get similar errors from when deploying the app, or only the adapter?

You must first do the above before you will be able to deploy the adapter from either Worklight Console or the Ant deployer script.

Comment: I have fully cleaned and rebuilt the project (apps and adapters) several times inside the Worklight Studio 6.0.0.1 (same plugin level of the server), without solving the problem.

Relating to app deployment, I'm getting another kind of error that I'm going to post in a separated thread. Anyway, while the common.wlapp deploys successfully the ipad.wlapp and mobile web.wlapp got a really strange SQL error.

Comment: I furtherly looked at the internal WRKLIGHT db and I found that the old apps and adapters were still stored into the internal table. Once cleaned up those tables adapter have deployed successfully.
Thank you for your help.