# Worklight Server error syncAdaptersFromDB

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We've just upgraded our Worklight server to 6.0.0.20140208-1639, and we're now frequently getting in the Websphere standard out log the error:

```
DeployService W com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl syncAdaptersFromDB FWLSE0082W: Failed to deploy adapter. This may be due to a JavaScript error in your adapter implementation (archive:  'C:\Windows\TEMP\HelloWorld6506022860570731839.adapter'). [project worklightEMS]
                                 com.worklight.gadgets.bean.InvalidDeployableException: The 'adapter' version 'null' is different than the version of Worklight Server '6.0.0'. 
Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl.syncAdaptersFromDB(DeployServiceImpl.java:167)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl.access$000(DeployServiceImpl.java:73)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl$ClusterSyncAdaptersTransaction.run(DeployServiceImpl.java:513)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl$ClusterSyncAdaptersTransaction.run(DeployServiceImpl.java:502)
    at com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils.doInTransaction(RssBrokerUtils.java:132)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl.syncAdaptersFromDBTransaction(DeployServiceImpl.java:499)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.bean.ClusterDataSynchronizationTask.step(ClusterDataSynchronizationTask.java:42)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:111)
```

There is no "HelloWorld" adapter in **c:\Windows\TEMP** and we can't find any reference to this in the WL project that was deployed to the server.  We rebuilt the WAR and deployed to the server using the same patch release.

Any idea why this error is being triggered and what we can do to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The following are pretty much the issue as yours:

- [Issues of migrating Worklight from v6.0 to v6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977617/issues-of-migrating-worklight-from-v6-0-to-v6-1)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Adapter disappears after it is deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949167/ibm-worklight-6-0-adapter-disappears-after-it-is-deployed/22047024#22047024)
- [IBM Worklight - Project built on 6.1 will not deploy on 6.1 server, says I need to use 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637642/ibm-worklight-project-built-on-6-1-will-not-deploy-on-6-1-server-says-i-need)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Error deploying adapters to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427326/ibm-worklight-6-0-0-1-error-deploying-adapters-to-server)
- [Worklight Server - Failed to deploy adapter 'LinkAccount.adapter'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372513/worklight-server-failed-to-deploy-adapter-linkaccount-adapter)

I recommend to review all answers to the above questions. 
You can then try to (or/and anything else that will be suggested above):

- Rebuild all artifacts (.wlapp, .adapter) with the new Worklight Studio build
- Make sure the updated Worklight Server version is installed in the application server
- Deploy the freshly generated .war file by Worklight Studio
- Deploy all artifacts